# Set Selection in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have multiple views in a horizontalscrollview, in an activity (view1, view2, view3 to viewN) for N-views. When i come to this activity, view1 is the the first visible item in the horizontalscrollview. But I want to start with view5 or view6 to be the first visible item in my horizontalscrollview, so when i swipe left to right, it shows up as all views view1, view2 upto view4 before that view5.

Answer (score 0):

```
horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(view5.getLeft());
    }
});
```

This waits until the views have been measured, then scrolls the scrollview to the coordinates of view5.

Haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: views are dynamic and are added to linear layout which in turn is added to horizontalscrollview , as horizontalscrollview supports only one child. so how to use your posted answer